# New line in reading file from user input

Tags: java, file, user-interface, io

What I am trying to do is write a record to new line in my text file. Every time someone clicks sign up on my program, I want to call a method that opens a file and adds a record. This is what I have now:

To open the file:

```
try {
    l = new Formatter("chineses.txt");
    System.out.println("Did create");
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Did not create");
}
```

To add the record:

```
public void addRecord(){
    l.format("%s", nameField.getText());
}
```

Every time I put in a name in the name field and click sign up in my GUI, it always replaces whatever is on the first line in the text file.
        How can I make it write to the second line while retaining what is on the first line?

Comment: Have you thought about changing how you are going about your problem space? This would be a excellent use of Javas Built in API called Properties. [Properties Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), [Java Properties Examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) These will simplify your word by a lot! You could use them in multiple ways! Even create a class that does the translation from the class to properties for you!

Comment: Why not use a PrintWriter with append.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using RandomAccessFile? You can seek to the end, then write.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.String)) a formater created with a single String argument will first empty the file (truncate to zero length) before writing to it. This is why your file is not appended to. The program first removes whatever is in the file and then writes the new content to it when you call l.format().

What you probably want to do is format your data to a String using [Formatter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter()). Open your record file for appending and then write that string to the file. [This link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) should have plenty of details on how you might do this. (I googled "java open and write a file" to find that resource)